# TimeMachine: how to identify which files are bloating the backups?

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine

I just started a TimeMachine backup after having only negligible changes to files on my HD (as far as I can tell). Yet the backup is shown to be of ~6GB (!!)

Is there some easy way for me to see which files make up those 6GB that TM is trying to back up?

Comment: I found out that the space hogs were MobileSync backups of iDevices....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the GUI tool called [TimeTracker](http://charlessoft.com/) (direct download link [here](http://www.charlessoft.com/TimeTracker.zip)):

> TimeTracker is a quick-and-dirty application that displays the contents of your Time Machine backups, and shows what's changed since the previous backup

That should suffice to examine your backups.

---

On OS X 10.7, the [**`tmutil`**](http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/tmutil/) command will probably let you do the same, albeit only through the command line. To compare your current OS X state and the latest backup, run:

```
tmutil compare
```

You can also compare two snapshots with each other, e.g. the latest two:

```
tmutil compare <path-to-snapshot> <path-to-snapshot>
```

… where the path to the snapshot is on your Time Machine volume, within the `Backups.backupdb` folder.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to TimeTracker and tmutil is [BackupLoupe](http://soma-zone.com/BackupLoupe/). It has a nice graphical interface and helps you to find big differences by color-coding.

Comment: … only that it costs $5 :)

Comment: He asked for an 'easy' tool not a free one. And sincerely 5$ is not the end of the world if it fits the needs.

Comment: Yeah, absolutely. I have no problem with paying for software if it's useful. Just thought I'd mention it, as some people don't really like to spend money.

Comment: In any case: it is possible to download it and try it before paying ...